# Sobel and Laplace results appear in grayscale

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, gradient, sobel

I have been trying to follow the tutorial on image gradients found on this link
https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html

The results for Laplacian, Sobel x, and Sobel y appear in black and white according to the tutorial. But my results appear in gray.
[image]

I cannot seem to find the reason since I am using the exact same code and the same sample image.

Comment: This is likely an issue with the colormap. Anyway the code in that example does not work for me (`cv2.__version__ = 3.2.0`)

Comment: It is because of negative values, just threshold all negative values to zero

Comment: @user8190410 Setting all negative values to zero is throwing away half the information. That is bad advice. The gradient as produced by OP is correct and should be used as-is. The OpenCV tutorial linked to is… of dubious quality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very late, but if someone encounters the same problem, my guess is you forgot to take the absolute value of your results (so the 0 values appear in gray because they are the center between the negative and positive peaks)

Comment: What is the purpose of taking the absolute value of a derivative? If you don’t know how something will be used, transforming it in a destructive way is not good.

Comment: In image processing, derivative operators (eg sobel/laplacian) are used to measure "how much the value varies". Pretty often they are associated with contour detection. In that case, you want high values to mean "the data varies a lot", and low values to mean "the data looks pretty constant". Taking the absolute value is a quick and dirty way to do that, and it looks like that’s what the tutorial is doing. Of course in practice, for more advanced algorithms (eg Canny), you’re going to want to keep the direction of the derivative

Answer (score 0):

The linked tutorial doesn’t seem to have a purpose beyond showing how to call these filtering functions. In this tutorial, they decided to clamp negative values to 0 (first part) or take the absolute values (second part), but don’t give a reasoning for doing so. Both approaches destroy data, making the resulting derivatives meaningless.

OP’s visualization is arguably more useful: zero appears as gray, with negative values being darker and positive values lighter. It is also possible to use [a divergent colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html#diverging), mapping zero to the halfway point on this map.

---

By the way, in the tutorial it says

> In our last example, output datatype is `cv2.CV_8U` […]

However, the code explicitly sets the output data type to `cv2.CV_64F`. The images match the text, not the code. If you were to set the output type to 8-bit unsigned integer, you should see the same images (but don’t do this!)